# device file open failed in linux system

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, uart

I am working in omap4 based system. It has 4 UART port so kernel makes:

```
/dev/ttyO0
/dev/ttyO1
/dev/ttyO2
/dev/ttyO3
```

When I open from user space:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyO1",O_RDONLY)
```

it succesfully open and i can peform read and write with that.

But when I open:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyO3",O_RDONLY)
```

Its failed.

I am able to see `/dev/ttyO3` node in my system still why i am not able to open it? Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean "O" or "0"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams its capital O

Comment: Check for a typo. It might be the digit 0 not the capital letter O (or vice versa)

Comment: You open the device *O_RDONLY*, and you claim you can *"read and write"*??!!  You need to print out the **errno** after the "failure".

Comment: Your premise is fundamentally mistaken.  Although they are a reference to in-kernel objects, **device nodes are not created by the kernel**, instead they must be created from userspace, either by a daemon such as udev or (on a simpler system) they may be created by a script using `mknod` either at runtime or during the creation of a persistent filesystem image.  Permissions on device nodes could be set when they are created, or later with `chmod` as you ended up doing.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27380822/1971003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have given permission to that node and now i can open that node

```
chmod 0606 /dev/ttyO3
```