# Miscellaneous Device Driver: Unable to open the device with open() system call

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, device-driver

I am trying to implement a system call interception for sys_open() call via kernel module and for that I have defined a miscellaneous device driver MyDevice which can be inserted as kernel module. Below is the code for my kernel module:

```
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/highmem.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

// IOCTL commands
#define IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE 0x00000001
#define IOCTL_FIX_TABLE 0x00000004

//Global variables
int in_use = 0; //set to 1 in open handler and reset to zero in release handler
int is_set = 0; // flag to detect system call interception
unsigned long *sys_call_table = (unsigned long*)0xffffffff81801400; //hard coded address of sys_call_table from /boot/System.map

//function pointer to original sys_open
asmlinkage int (*real_open)(const char* __user, int, int);

//Replacement of original call with modified system call
asmlinkage int custom_open(const char* __user file_name, int flags, int mode)
{
    printk("interceptor: open(\"%s\", %X, %X)\n", file_name,flags,mode);
    return real_open(file_name,flags,mode);
}

/*
Make the memory page writable
This is little risky as directly arch level protection bit is changed
*/
int make_rw(unsigned long address)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    if(pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW)
        pte->pte |= _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

/* Make the page write protected */
int make_ro(unsigned long address)
{
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~ _PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

/* This function will be invoked each time a user process attempts
       to open my device. You should keep in mind that the prototype
      of this function may change along different kernel versions. */
static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    /*Do not allow multiple processes to open this device*/
    if(in_use)
        return -EBUSY;
    in_use++;
    printk("MyDevice opened\n");
    return 0;
}

/* This function, in turn, will be called when a process closes our device */
static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    in_use--;
    printk("MyDevice closed\n");
    return 0;
}

/*This static function handles ioctl calls performed on MyDevice*/
static int my_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    int retval = 0;

    switch(cmd)
   {
      case IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE:
         make_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
         real_open = (void*)*(sys_call_table + __NR_open);
         *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned long)custom_open;
         make_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
         is_set=1;
         break;
      case IOCTL_FIX_TABLE:
         make_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
         *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned long)real_open;
         make_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
         is_set=0;
         break;
      default:
         printk("sys_open not executed\n");
         break;
   }

    return retval;
}

//populate data struct for file operations
static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = &my_open,
    .release = &my_release,
    .unlocked_ioctl = (void*)&my_ioctl,
    .compat_ioctl = (void*)&my_ioctl
};

//populate miscdevice data structure
static struct miscdevice my_device = {
    MISC_DYNAMIC_MINOR,
    "MyDevice",
    &my_fops
};

static int __init init_my_module(void)
{
    int retval;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Inside kernel space\n");
    retval = misc_register(&my_device);
    return retval;
}

static void __exit cleanup_my_module(void)
{
    if (is_set)
    {
        make_rw((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
        *(sys_call_table + __NR_open) = (unsigned long)real_open;
        make_ro((unsigned long)sys_call_table);
    }

    misc_deregister(&my_device);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Exiting kernel space\n");
    return;
}

module_init(init_my_module);
module_exit(cleanup_my_module);
```

The code for my test file is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


/* Define ioctl commands */
#define IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE 0x00000001
#define IOCTL_FIX_TABLE   0x00000004


int main(void)
{
   int device = open("/dev/MyDevice", O_RDWR);
   printf("%d\n",device);
   ioctl(device, IOCTL_PATCH_TABLE);
   sleep(2);
   ioctl(device, IOCTL_FIX_TABLE);
   close(device);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that in my test file open("/dev/MyDevice", O_RDWR); is always returning -1, why is it so ? Where am I going wrong ? I checked with ls -l /dev/MyDevice,  MyDevice has been successfully registered with following details: crw------- 1 root root 10, 56 Dec  9 19:33 /dev/MyDevice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, seriously stupid mistake, that's what happens when rookies do things. I just needed to grant the read and write permissions for my miscellaneous char device driver.

```
sudo chmod a+r+w /dev/MyDevice
```

Comment: I faced the same issue :) , is it possible to set the permissions to the device node file in the code and not manually (i.e. - in the open method) ? Is it wise to do so ? Thanks !!